# PIP not installing on a windows 10 and python 3.7.3

Tags: python, command-prompt

I'm trying to install PIP on my windows 10 laptop and every time I run the command to install it nothing happens.

I've tried running the command in the administrative command prompt as well as the PowerShell and Admin PowerShell.

After I downloaded the get-pip.py file I ran the command

```
cd Downloads
```

then

```
python get-pip.py
```

and this is the output.

Yes. Nothing.

I hope I can get this problem resolved.

Thanks in advance,
Megastrik3

Comment: What's the content of `get-pip.py` file?! Pip comes with Python windows installer.

To update `pip` run: `> pip install pip -U` (this is all built-in).

Comment: Do I run that command in the command prompt?

Comment: Yes in the command prompt / powershell. It should find pip fine if you installed Python with "Add PATH" ticked.

Comment: Oh, ok. I think that might be the problem. I didn't install python the PATH. I'll do that then try...

Comment: Awesome! It worked! I guess it was because I didn't install python to PATH.